# Allow multiple registrations from the same email address requires a profile of type 'Individual'

Tags: civievent, drupal, custom-fields, error, duplicate-contacts

Long time ago, we had created event and template for event.
We give permission to user to register multiple participant with same email address.

Now we have problem with a lot of question link to participant.

At this time we receive this error : 
"*Allow multiple registrations from the same email address requires a profile of type 'Individual'"*

I think problem is comming from dedupe rules but I can resolved it.
I have create new one but it change nothing. I received this error

But I receive error when I was creating new user more detailed error like this :

```
#0 /home/username/etuc/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(187): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 [internal function](): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /usr/share/php/PEAR.php(890): call_user_func((Array:2), Object(DB_Error))
#3 /home/username/etuc/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB.php(976): PEAR_Error->PEAR_Error("DB Error: constraint violation", -3, 16, (Array:2), "DELETE FROM civicrm_dedupe_rule_group  WHERE (  civicrm_dedupe_rule_group.id ...")
#4 /usr/share/php/PEAR.php(531): DB_Error->DB_Error(-3, 16, (Array:2), "DELETE FROM civicrm_dedupe_rule_group  WHERE (  civicrm_dedupe_rule_group.id ...")
#5 /home/username/etuc/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1905): PEAR->raiseError(NULL, -3, NULL, NULL, "DELETE FROM civicrm_dedupe_rule_group  WHERE (  civicrm_dedupe_rule_group.id ...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#6 /home/username/etuc/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysql.php(895): DB_common->raiseError(-3, NULL, NULL, NULL, "1451 ** Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails ...")
#7 /home/username/etuc/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysql.php(328): DB_mysql->mysqlRaiseError()
#8 /home/username/etuc/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysql->simpleQuery("DELETE FROM civicrm_dedupe_rule_group  WHERE (  civicrm_dedupe_rule_group.id ...")
#9 /home/username/etuc/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2438): DB_common->query("DELETE FROM civicrm_dedupe_rule_group  WHERE (  civicrm_dedupe_rule_group.id ...")
#10 /home/username/etuc/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1449): DB_DataObject->_query("DELETE FROM civicrm_dedupe_rule_group  WHERE (  civicrm_dedupe_rule_group.id ...")
#11 /home/username/etuc/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(519): DB_DataObject->delete(FALSE)
#12 /home/username/etuc/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Page/DedupeRules.php(218): CRM_Core_DAO->delete()
#13 /home/username/etuc/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contact/Page/DedupeRules.php(123): CRM_Contact_Page_DedupeRules->delete("1")
#14 /home/username/etuc/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(312): CRM_Contact_Page_DedupeRules->run((Array:3), NULL)
#15 /home/username/etuc/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(86): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#16 /home/username/etuc/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(54): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#17 /home/username/etuc/docroot/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(448): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#18 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("contact", "deduperules")
#19 /home/username/etuc/docroot/includes/menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:2))
#20 /home/username/etuc/docroot/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#21 {main}

Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment
"Supervised rule for Indivual does not exist"
```

How have the same problems? What are solutions?

Thanks a lot.

NI

Answer (score 1):

The list line is probably the information you need

> "Supervised rule for Indivual does not exist"

Go to your Duplicate matching rules and confirm if this is missing and create it.

/civicrm/contact/deduperules?reset=1

Read the book on DeDupe rules if you need more info on creating Rules.

Comment: Thanks for your response but we have a lot of different dedupe rules on this page.

Comment: Hi - a 'lot' is not the same has having a 'Supervised rule for Individual'. And that is what the error says so is the only thing we have to go on and try to help you. Do you want to add a screenshot of your Rules to the original question to help rule that out.